# intellij/scala/play application not building - port bind error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka, playframework-2.6

I am unable to build my `scala`/`play` application.

```
[error] a.i.TcpListener - Bind failed for TCP channel on endpoint [/0.0.0.0:9000]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at akka.io.TcpListener.liftedTree1$1(TcpListener.scala:56)
    at akka.io.TcpListener.<init>(TcpListener.scala:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
akka.stream.impl.io.ConnectionSourceStage$$anon$2$$anon$1: Bind failed because of Address already in use: bind
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at akka.io.TcpListener.liftedTree1$1(TcpListener.scala:56)
    at akka.io.TcpListener.<init>(TcpListener.scala:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at akka.util.Reflect$.instantiate(Reflect.scala:65)
    at akka.actor.ArgsReflectConstructor.produce(IndirectActorProducer.scala:96)
    at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:213)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:626)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:652)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:525)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:547)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:282)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:223)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last compile:run' for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed 01-Jun-2020 19:58:45
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Interestingly, the process occupying the port `9000` is idea.exe!!

[image]

Comment: What ports do you have specified in the run/debug configuration here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html#run_debug_play ? Does it help if you specify a different HTTP port by adding `-Dhttp.port=9090` in the VM Options field of the Run configuration?

Comment: yes, that works. What might be wrong with 9000? Is there a way I can use 9000?

Comment: Some plug-in you have may be using this port (such as Xdebugger if you are using PHP), there is nothing in IntelliJ IDEA that would use it by default. Or there may be some misconfiguration like the debugger port set to the same value as HTTP port.

Comment: It was PHP! I uninstalled the plugin and now I have my port back. Thanks. Happy to accept your answer if you please create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP plug-in may use port 9000 for XDebug. Either disable the plug-in or change the port via VM Options in the Run confuguration like this: `-Dhttp.port=9090`.